# remove first line of text

Tags: bash

Why does this script work with the old version of the file?

I want to remove the first line of a csv if the line contains the text `KP_TITEL`
If i test the script with an exit after `sed` everything works fine. But as soon as I want to test it with the `while loop` the file still contains the first line.

Any Idea?

```
sed -i '/KP_TITEL/d' "$1"

# read data
input=$1

while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13
do

  other things

done < "$input"
```

Comment: TITEL is not TITLE! Copy & Paste error?

Comment: just a error in my description, but the program works without the while part.... it removes the first line. but the while loop does not work with the right file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the option `-i` does for `sed` but usually, `sed` is a stream editor which processed the input and writes the result to stdout. In your case, the output is lost and then, the old file is read again by while. Try this instead:

```
sed '/KP_TITEL/d' "$1" | \
while ...
done
```

The pipe symbol will change the `stdin` of the while loop (and hence the `read` command).

I continue the line with `\` since I find this more readable than:

```
sed '/KP_TITEL/d' "$1" | while ...
```

And to delete the first line, you should use either

```
sed 1d "$1"
```

or (cheaper)

```
tail --lines=+2 "$1"
```

Comment: `-i` should change the file *i*n place.

Comment: It depends on `sed` implementations. Sometimes `-i''` is needed instead of a bare `-i`

Comment: @choroba: That's dangerous plus there is no need to change the file at all. Lastly, there are better ways to filter the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to deal with all but the first line (say through a pipe) you can achieve this with `tail`:

```
tail -n +2 $file
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a counter

```
g=0;

while ...

((g++))
        if [ "$g" != "1" ]; then
                do something
        fi
done
```